# Remover shadow-box e ajustar tamanho do container

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-3

Estou com uma dificuldade em fazer alguns ajustes em uma pagina

Estou usando o BootStrap3, e só consigo fazer as configurações no Clientside

Gostaria de remover o box shadow de um `jumotron.btn`

```
box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.18),0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15)
```

e altear o tamanho do `container` de `70%` para `40%`

em qual arquivo devo fazer essas alterações? no `CSS` padrão não encontrei.

quando abro o console encontro esse link,

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/css/materialize.min.css
```

Sou novo nessa parte de Web, se puderem dar uma luz.

Comment: Você pode fazer um css próprio para sobrescrever essas propriedades, assim você não mexe nos arquivos originais e consegue compreender melhor o que está sendo/ou não alterado.

Comment: eu tentei usar alguns !important, mas sem sucesso

Comment: Você precisa ver a hierarquia toda do arquivo. Em alguns definir apenas `.container {}` não vai adiantar se ele possuir uma hierarquia mais profunda, ex: `.section .row .container {}` e `!important` também não é a melhor saida. Outra coisa que pode interferir é o load do arquivo. Se não me falha a memória, o seu css deve ser carregado após o css do bootstrap, para que possa sobrescrever os arquivos.

Comment: Consegui remover o shadow, porem o problema do width ainda não consigo alterar, acredito que seja a mesma ideia.

Comment: Provavelmente. Tente procurar o arquivo src equivalente ao css que você está fazendo load, vai ser mais fácil de identificar. Pois o que está em load é o .min.css que é mais difícil de manter.

Comment: Você tentou procurar no [arquivo expandido](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/css/materialize.css)?

Comment: GuilhermeLima faça como o @CelsomTrindade disse, sobreponha com um CSS separado (por exemplo, declarado depois do Bootstrap.). O importante é que o seu seja o mais específico possível para sua instrução sobrepor a original. O `!important` usualmente é um recurso pra se usar em casos mais extremos. O inspetor dos browsers normalmente mostra a hierarquia toda do CSS, use-o para determinar onde mexer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um novo arquivo .css e faça as alterações lá, sempre colocando !important
Assim que se deve fazer ao usar bootstrap

No novo arquivo criado, ponha isso:

```
.jumbotron .btn{
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0),0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;   
}
```

Comment: valeu broder, ja tinha feito isso mas ta ai pra quem precisar

Comment: Feliz em ter conseguido.